# Chromecast - Lock screen/Notification/Mini Controller - Stop Button instead of a Pause button

Tags: android, chromecast

I've implemented Cast SDK 3 into my application for Android, everything is working as expected when following the guidelines from the Cast SDK website, the only thing that I can't wrap my head around is the button for play_pause_toggle_button, the screen shot from the Cast SDK website shows a proper pause button, but I get stop button instead (in which pauses the video) is there something I'm not doing correctly that may not be obvious?

First post, please go easy :)

Comment: Your question lacks information, code samples and screen shots. Without those it's hard for us to guess what's going wrong. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am stuck with a pause button and needing a stop button (I have tried the answer below and am still stuck!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to guess, I would say you have set the stream type of your `MediaInfo` objects to `MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE`. If so, change them to `MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED` and see if that fixes your problem.